# Dictionary for finding orientation of the words

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I am looking for a dictionary that finds the orientation(positive/negative/neutral) of the words as part of analyzing the sentiment of the phrase. Preferably a source that can be imported into python code

Comment: See perhaps here: https://finnaarupnielsen.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/simplest-sentiment-analysis-in-python-with-af/

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for something like [OpinionFinder](http://mpqa.cs.pitt.edu/lexicons/subj_lexicon/).

This particular link points to a lexicon of 8233 adjectives, verbs and nouns and their orientation.

You can download it, so you'll be able to simply read the file into python.

Answer (score 1):

From [SentiWordNet](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it) website:

> SentiWordNet is a lexical resource for opinion mining. SentiWordNet
>   assigns to each synset of WordNet three sentiment scores: positivity,
>   negativity, objectivity

There are a lot of Python frameworks that use Wordnet and Sentiwordnet, such as NLTK or Pattern.